# Use a UIImage with text or UILabel for automatically scaled text

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage, uilabel

I have text that needs to be scaled for each iOS device depending on the screen size. Apparently, you can't scale UILabel font size automatically except manually code wise (unless I am missing something). Instead of having to code for a lot of scenarios, would it be better to use an UIImage that has all the text? This way I can make the text scale automatically depending on device size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a `UILabel`'s text scale automatically by (1) setting auto layout constraints for that `UILabel` such that its height and width are relative to the screen size, (2) setting the label's base font to at least the size which it would be on the largest screen, then (3) setting its "auto shrink" property such that its minimum font scale or minimum font size would be at least as small as the font on the smallest screen.

I do not recommend using an `UIImage` instead because you wouldn't be able to edit or localize it as easily.

Comment: Oh, forgot all about that. Thank you. I will implement this immediatley. Basically just make the UILabel for the biggest screen, setup constraints to make the UILabel get bigger or smaller depending on size and finally set the minimum font size.